# JS Сравнение id и вывод подходящей картинки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть галерея маленьких картинок. При клике на каждую должно появляться ее увеличенное изображение.

```
<ul id="list">
    <li class="list-item" data-id='1'><img id="1" src="./task-2/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li class="list-item" data-id='2'><img id="2" src="./task-2/2.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li class="list-item" data-id='3'><img id="3" src="./task-2/3.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

Я реализовал отображение id li.

```
let parag = document.createElement('div');
$('.list-item').click((event) => {
    const imgId = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id');
    parag.innerHTML = imgId;
    document.getElementById('modalContent').insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', parag)
});

$('.close').click((e) => {
    parag.innerHTML = " ";})
```

Как отобразить вместо цифры картинку с таким же id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```js
$('.list-item').click((event) => {
    // const imgId = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id');
    const imgSrc = event.currentTarget.querySelector('img').getAttribute('src');
    parag.innerHTML = `<img src="${imgSrc}">`;
    document.getElementById('modalContent').insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', parag)
});
```

Comment: Да, получилось! Спасибо!

Comment: Если не сложно, обьясни суть, пожалуйста)

Comment: Мы ищем внутри блока, на который тыкнули элемент img и берем его атрибут src.

Comment: Если ответ оказался полезен, нажмите стрелочку вверх и если ответ решает ваш вопрос - галочку.

Comment: А после просто вставляем img с путем , который нашли. да?

Comment: Да. Вы правильно поняли.

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался.

Comment: Можно вопрос? Что за смесь JQ и чистого JS?)

Comment: Так получилось, но перепишу чистый)